# Is there any reason that Landau and Lifshitz don't discuss Noether's theorem in their mechanics book?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, noethers-theorem

I'm currently working my way through the *Course* volume one. Unless I've completely missed it, the authors omit any discussion of Noether's theorem, instead deriving various conservation laws on a case by case basis. L&L certainly knew about the theorem, so why might they choose to leave it out? Is there some historical reason, or do they include it in another book, or something else entirely?

Comment: Are they allowed a choice of what they include or not? It is their textbook to write....

Comment: Of course! It's just strange that they'd choose to leave out one of the most important theorems of the 20th century...

Comment: Could have something to do with cold-war politics. There were non-trivial cultural difference between Soviet and "western" (is there a better adjective?) physics culture through much of the twentieth century. You could see if this could be formulated in terms suitable for [hsm.se].